# Set UIDatePicker Timezone to simulater's current timezone

Tags: ios, xcode, datetime, nsdate, uidatepicker

i have UIDatePicker. i cant set timezone to that...
My code is...

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
datePicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
datePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

dateChanged method...

```
-(void)dateChanged:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"%@",[sender date]);
}
```

log returns
2014-07-26 12:54:11 +0000

i want local timezone in simulater

i also tried

```
datePicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
```

and

```
datePicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
```

Log always returns 
+0000 timezone only
but simulater timezone is GMT +5.30

sorry for my bad english

Plz help me...

Comment: An NSDate is, by definition, a GMT value.  Timezone is involved only when the date is parsed or formatted.

Comment: UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init]; this code initializes the current date in system but timezone +0000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A date object is a "raw" date always in GMT.

Try something like this

```
NSLog(@"date with local timezone is: %@", [date descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]]);
```

Also look documentation for NSDateFormatter.